# Azure Storage copy an image from blob to blob

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using `Azure Storage Nodejs` and what i need to do is to copy image from one blob to another.
First i tried to `getBlobToFile` to get the image on temp location in disk and then just `createBlockBlobFromFile` from that temp location. That method did the task, but for some reason it didn't copied completely in 10% of cases.
The i was trying to use `getBlobToText` and the result of that put into `createBlockBlobFromText`, also tried to put options which is need blob to be image container. That method failed completely, image not even opened after copy.
Perhaps there is a way to copy blob file and paste it in other blobl but i didn't find that method.
What else can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what your particular copy-error is, but... with `getLocalBlobToFile()`, you're actually physically moving blob content from blob storage to your VM (or local machine), and then with `createBlockBlobFromLocalFile()` you're pushing the entire contents back to blob storage, which is resulting in two physical network moves.

The Azure Storage system supports blob-copy as a 1st-class operation. While it's available via REST API call, it's also wrapped in the same SDK you're using, in the method `BlobService.startCopyBlob()` (source code [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L2183)). This will instruct the storage to initiate an async copy operation, completely within the storage system (meaning no download+upload on your side). You'll be able to set source and destination, set timeouts, etc. (all parameters are fully documented in the source code).

Comment: Awesome one, haven't noticed that. Thank you

Comment: Is there any good way of getting sourceUri? getBlobProperties don't have that information.

Comment: Updated link to MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url

Comment: @tim - thanks for posting that link, though that is specifically documentation for the REST API (which I hadn't included in my original answer 4 years ago). Since the source code link was out-of-date, I just updated it to point to the latest SDK source (which still fully documents all parameters required for the method call).

Answer (score 0):

The link in the accepted answer is broken, although the method is correct: the method `startCopyBlob` is documented here

(Updated: Jan 3, 2020) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/BlobService?view=azure-node-latest#azure_storage_BlobService_createBlockBlobFromLocalFile

(The old link) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/BlobService?view=azure-node-latest#azure_storage_BlobService_createBlockBlobFromLocalFile

Comment: Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url